# How to change private indooratlas map to public ?

Tags: indoor-positioning-system

I just mapping my building as private mode in Indooratlas app, and it is public state in default.

But I want to share information with other people as `public` map information.

How to change private indooratlas map to public ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you login to app.indooratlas.com, open your location and then press "Edit details" under location details on the right. You can then switch "Allow other users to see this location and its floorplans". Please note that all other IndoorAtlas users can then find your location in the world map with the MapCreator tool.